# Is there ability of translation of Json values on Azure Cognitive Services. I'm wondering the implementation on .Net core

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I want to translate my Json values from one language to other languages but through the Azure Cognitive Services I can't rich my expectations.

Simple Text and Html based text were translating through Azure translator but Json values I don't know how implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the azure cognitive services in azure portal. Create cognitive services using valid subscription and resource group with valid storage policy and public access.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Input of JSON:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "Consolidaciones": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anónimo",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "nombre": "req",
      "métodos": [
        "obtener",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tipo": "http",
      "dirección": "fuera",
      "nombre": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

**View Request:**

```
[{
    "text": "{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}"
}]
```

**View Response:**

```
[{
    "detectedLanguage": {
        "language": "en",
        "score": "1"
    }}
    "translations": [{
        "text": "{
  "Consolidaciones": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anónimo",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "nombre": "req",
      "métodos": [
        "obtener",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tipo": "http",
      "dirección": "fuera",
      "nombre": "res"
    }
  ]
}",
        "to": "es"
    }]
}]
```

Create Source and Destination containers in the storage account. In the form of folders and upload JSON file to be translated into the source code and get all the keys mentioned above and modify in the below code block.

**Code Block in C#**

```
using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Text;


    class Program
    {

        static readonly string route = "/batches";

        private static readonly string endpoint = "https://<NAME-OF-YOUR-RESOURCE>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/translator/text/batch/v1.0";

        private static readonly string key = "<YOUR-KEY>";

        static readonly string json = ("{\"inputs\": [{\"source\": {\"sourceUrl\": \"https://YOUR-SOURCE-URL-WITH-READ-LIST-ACCESS-SAS\",\"storageSource\": \"AzureBlob\",\"language\": \"en\"}, \"targets\": [{\"targetUrl\": \"https://YOUR-TARGET-URL-WITH-WRITE-LIST-ACCESS-SAS\",\"storageSource\": \"AzureBlob\",\"category\": \"general\",\"language\": \"es\"}]}]}");

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            {

                StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(endpoint + route);
                request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);
                request.Content = content;

                HttpResponseMessage  response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Response Headers:");
                    Console.WriteLine(response.Headers);
                }
                else
                    Console.Write("Error");

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: thank you to your reply, but I already checked Azure Translation Service. This service is good for text and html translation but for Json translation it doesn't understand Json key/value pair. It sees everything as a text. Unfortunately, Azure Translation Service doesn't translate Json value, it translates like as a text.

Comment: Currently that exact feature is not yet available, but alternative approach is the procedure mentioned in the solution.